# Is there a service that generates embed HTML from a link?

Tags: html, embed

I'm writing an app that involves posting content, and I'd like people's input to be in the form of plain text, but auto-embed content that's linked to, a la Facebook.  Is there a service that generates HTML to embed linked content on a per-site basis?  For example, YouTube links would return embed code for the video, images would return a thumbnail, Facebook profiles would return a profile picture+name, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to use url extracting and preg_match or/and preg_replace functions of php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for this: http://www.addthis.com/

Comment: That doesn't sound like what he is looking for, but I'll let him clarify if so.

Comment: @Brad's right, this isn't what I'm looking for.  Do you have any suggestions on how to clarify?